# numpy.nonzero() with combinatorial logic

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like to use numpy.nonzero() with combinatorial logic but my attempt ends up like this:

```
>>> x
array([[  3,   5,   4,   2,   2],
       [  2,   5,   3, 100,   4],
       [  3,   5,   4, 100,   3]])
>>> np.nonzero(x > 3 and x < 100)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

But it's unclear how to apply any() or all() in this case.
Do I have to split into two steps and then use setdiff()?
That would be so sad.

Comment: Did you look at: `x > 3 and x < 100`?  For some reason this error message confuses people, and they don't think to pick apart the generating expression.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the operator & to get the result that you expect:

```
np.nonzero((x > 3) & (x < 100))
```

& does the element-wise "and"

Comment: Thank you! I see. I tried & too. But I missed the () around the individual logic expressions.

Comment: To avoid confusion, you could utilize ``np.logical_and()`` and ``np.bitwise_and()``.